# how to check if current page is login page and how to check current page is registration page

Tags: magento-1.9, login, register

i am using magento 1.9.2.4 and i am creating a module that will check if page is not registration page or login then it will redirect to home page  is there any way to know that if current page is login page or customer registration page ? thanx in advance.

Comment: you can find it by controller and action name in request

Comment: thanx @GopalPatel got it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call below function in your template and get page info in magento 1
,

```
 $request = $this->getRequest();
 $modulename = $request->getModuleName();
 $controller = $request->getControllerName();
 $action = $request->getActionName();
 if($modulename == 'customer' && $controller == 'account' && $action == 'login')
 {
   //login page
 }

  if($modulename == 'customer' && $controller == 'account' && $action == 'create')
 {
   //registration page
 }
```

Comment: exactly what i waiting for. thanx bro.